# DevExpress DXGrid column header double click event

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

I have to check / uncheck all the checkboxes (toggle) in a column when the user double clicks the column header.

How can I implement this behaviour in the [DevExpress DxGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WPF/Grid/) control?

I have searched the DevExpress support forum but I haven't found a solution.

Also, i am working on MVVM Pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This case works for WinForms, not tested in WPF yet, I posted might it direct you to some lights:

There is a workaround to accomplish this behave, you have to implement `yourGrid_DoubleClick` Event Handler, then calculate the `hit Info` of the mouse click, the hit info object will tell you if the double click was on a column, something like:

```
 private void yourGridViewName_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView sndr =
                    sender as DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView;

            DevExpress.Utils.DXMouseEventArgs dxMouseEventArgs =
                e as DevExpress.Utils.DXMouseEventArgs;


            DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.ViewInfo.GridHitInfo hitInfo =
               sndr.CalcHitInfo(dxMouseEventArgs.Location);

            if (hitInfo.InColumn)
            {
               string x = hitInfo.Column.Name;

              //Rest of your logic goes here after getting the column name, 
             //You might now loop over your grid's data and do your logic
           }
    }
```

but you have to notice that this action will not prevent the sorting that column's header do, you might need to disable sorting for this grid

Hope this helped.

Comment: thanx for the reply. I am alredy using mouse double click event.when i double click on a row i am checking /unchecking all cb of selected row successfully but for column cb checking/unckeing i have to implement column header double click event but don't know how...

Comment: use the same event `grdiDoubleClick` and check the `hitInfo.InColumn` property to indicate whether or not the user `double-clicked` column header or another part of the grid, this should worked for you.